# Ruby on rails - gmaps4rails - passing marker data. Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Hello I'm using paloma gem to separate some of my javascript. When trying to add a marker to the map I get the error `Maximum call stack size exceeded` from gmaps.

I am passing a variable (the marker coordinates) from my controller in json format to the js file, then adding that variable to an alert box (for testing) and the marker.

```
var arrCoo = this.params.hash;
alert(arrCoo);
markers = handler.addMarkers(arrCoo);
```

(`this.params.hash` calls the variable sent from my controller).
In this case, the alert box displays the coordinates eg:

```
[{"lat":57.4386015,"lng":16.6152354}]
```

but I get the error `Maximum call stack size exceeded` and the marker and map don't display.

---

If I copy and paste the coordinates;

```
markers = handler.addMarkers([{"lat":57.4386015,"lng":16.6152354}]);
```

then the marker shows on the map no problem.

---

In my case what is the difference between

```
markers = handler.addMarkers(arrCoo);
```

and

```
markers = handler.addMarkers([{"lat":57.4386015,"lng":16.6152354}]);
```

?? Why isn't the variable being seen the same way by the alert box and the marker attributes?

---

UPDATE:

I am adding more information. With the following code the alert shows the array of coordinates, but gmaps gives me the error. If I try and directly add `markers = handler.addMarkers(this.params.hash);` I get the error `cannot read property hash of undefined`. How can I put my array in without causing errors?

```
Paloma.controller('Gigs', {
  show: function(){

    var arrCoo = this.params.hash;


    var mapStyle = [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":33}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2e5d4"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#c5dac6"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#c5c6c6"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#e4d7c6"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#fbfaf7"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#acbcc9"}]}];
    var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
      handler.buildMap({
        provider: {
          mapTypeControl: false,
          streetViewControl: false,
          styles: mapStyle,
          zoom: 4,
          minZoom: 2,
          maxZoom: 20,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.68177501, -103.3514794)
        },
        internal: {id: 'gigmap'}},
        function(){

                  alert(arrCoo);
        markers = handler.addMarkers(arrCoo);
        handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
        handler.fitMapToBounds();
      });

}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Maximum call stack size exceeded` happens when a function calls another function and so on. When you chain a lot of function calls, you reach the maximum stack limit and get the error.

In your case, when you do `handler.addMarkers(arrCoo);` you call a function that internally calls other functions to draw the markers and returns the result.

The only solution is to simplify the function calls to reduce the stack

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, but is there any way I can do this then? I don't see any other way of passing this array from the controller to the js file.

Comment: I have updated my question with more information and my code.